# Software to draw simple technical illustrations

Tags: gratis, drawing, diagram

Looking for software to draw diagrams such as the technical drawings in Machinery's Handbook or a free body diagram. I think Inkscape is probably the answer but I'm having trouble getting things positioned exactly where I want them (I'm used to making sketches in SolidWorks, where I can add tangent and co-linear relationships). Maybe I just need to get to learn Inkscape a bit better?

[image: Technical Drawing]
[image: Free Body Diagrams]

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations.  We need more information to help you.  On which operating system(s) does this software need to run?  Are you looking for recommendations for gratis or commercial software?

Comment: The software should ideally run on Windows or Linux (I use Ubuntu), and be free software. I already have licenses for SolidWorks, and I can draw what I need in SolidWorks, but I don't know how to control things like line thickness, etc, from SolidWorks. Maybe I can export a sketch from SolidWorks into InkScape, so that way I have 90% of the work done for me.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question was supposed to be answered from here: [Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12797/software-for-simple-2d-technical-drawings)

CAD-PRO can help you out.This is what it does in brief; 
CAD-PRO is a technical drawing software,technical drawings are fast, easy and accurate.

**Roles**

1. Sketch Tracing – Sketch your drawings on a piece of paper, and then scan it. Now you open your scanned sketch in CAD Pro and it becomes a traceable template that you can easily modify.
2. Interactive features allow you to share your technical drawings with colleagues and friends.
3. Integrate your technical designs with Microsoft Office for presentations or manuals.

**Note** :I recommend you to visit this [site](https://www.cadpro.com/technical-drawings-drafting/) and find out more.

Answer (score 3):

[LibreCAD](http://librecad.org/cms/home.html) is a decent 2D CAD application.

- Free software
- Solid base functionality
- Maybe a bit clunky compared to some commercial solutions
- Cross platform